# Plivo - play a music while speaking a text in the same time

Tags: plivo

I'm using the [`<Play>`](https://www.plivo.com/docs/xml/play/) element to greet my clients in music :)

It works great but I'd like to use the [`Speak`](https://www.plivo.com/docs/xml/speak/) element as well, in the same time.

Does anybody knows if this is possible: **play a music while speaking a text in the same time**?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Play and Speak cannot be executed simultaneously using the XML. You could use one in the XML and execute the other using the API. For example, if you use Play in XML, you can use [Speak API](https://www.plivo.com/docs/api/call/speak/). To invoke the Speak API, you need the Call UUID of the ongoing call. Call UUID is usually passed on to the answer url. In case, your call has 2 legs (Aleg and Bleg), make sure that you use the correct Call UUID.